# Alterar um Select a partir de outro acionando o evento "onChange" do segundo utilizando JS

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery

Estou com dois problemas, fiz uma função para verificar pela classe dos selects todos os seus filhos no bloco, assim quando troco a primeira opção tem que trocar de todos os demais em cascata. Problemas:

(1) -> como ele está inserindo o "selected" ele não está acionando o "onChange" do produto

(2) -> quando eu altero a primeira vez ele aplica a todos os selects, mas se eu ficar trocando entre as opções ele só altera as que ainda não foram selecionadas (só funciona 1 vez)

JS com minha função

```
selectDepositoPadrao: function(event){
    // capturar o evento
    console.log(event.val());
    // pegar somente o bloco para poder alterar por classe cada option
    $(event).closest('.form-std')
        // buscando a mesma classe em comun nos depósitos
        .find('.depositoDestino')
        .each(function(idx,item){
            //ignora o primeiro
            if(idx) {
                //pega os values dos options dos selects
                $(item).children().each(function(idxOpt, itemOpt){
                    if($(itemOpt).val() === $(event).val()){

                        $(itemOpt).attr('selected', 'selected')
                    }
                })
            }
        });
},
```

Formulario que aciona ela

```
<select name="depositoPadraoCel" id="depositoPadraoCel" onchange="FormularioTransferencia.selectDepositoPadrao($(this))"
        class="depositoDestino">
</select>
```

OnChange que eu quero acionar que não está acionando (blade do Laravel)

```
     <select class="depositoDestino" 
name = "celular[{{$inputId}}][deposito_destino]" 
@if(isset($celular)) id="depositoDestinoCelular{{$celular->estoque_celular->es_id}}" 
    onchange="obtemProdutoStatusDoDeposito('{{$celular->estoque_celular->es_id}}', 'Celular')" @endif>
     <option value="" selected>Selecione o deposito</option>
      @if(isset($depositos))
         @foreach($depositos as $deposito)
         <option @if(isset($celular) && $deposito->id == $celular->deposito_destino_id) selected 
      @endif value="{{$deposito->id}}">
         {{$deposito->nome}}
     </option>
       @endforeach
        @endif
     </select>
```

Estou tentando buscar se tenho de utilizar somente o change do JS aplicando ele no  percorrendo por indices no lugar de adicionar o "selected" direto na  não sei se esse é o caminho correto.

Comment: ***(ultima frase) direto na "<option>" com o selected (nao consegui editar 2 vezes aqui...

Answer (score 0):

```
function selectDepositoPadrao(event){
    $(event).closest('.form-std')
        .find('.deposito')
        .each(function(idx,item){
            $(item).children().each(function(idxOpt, itemOpt){
               
                if ($(itemOpt).val() !== $(event).val()){
                    $(itemOpt).removeAttr('selected');
                } else {
                    $(itemOpt).removeAttr('selected');
                    $(itemOpt).attr('selected','selected');
                }
                $(itemOpt).parent().trigger('change');
            });
        });
}
```

consegui fazer dessa maneira, selecionando e realizando o trigger para acionar o onchange do outro select, só estou agora com outro problema referente a selecionar o item 1 depois vou no 2 e quando volto para o 1, ele reproduz corretamente os "selected" no html porém não muda a option, volta para a primeira option sem valor.